# Сортировка на Ruby

Tags: сортировка, ruby

Используя любую сортировку, нужно написать программу, которая будет сортировать входные строки по алфавиту.

```
и а ю я (а и ю я)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. Программа должна сортировать строки по алфавиту. Написана, как видите, на Ruby.

```
enter strings = Array.new
str = ""
count = 5
i = 0
k = 1
j = 0
n = 0 
#выводим считанные строки

while i< count   
    print "vvedite stroky: " 
    strings[i] = gets.to_s
    puts strings[i].to_s
    i +=1
end

#сортировка мотодом пузырька
while k < count
    while j < count - k 
        if(strings[j].casecmp(strings[j+1]) > 0)
            str = strings[j].clone
            strings[j] = strings[j+1].clone
            strings[j+1] = str.clone
        end 
        j +=1
    end
    k +=1
end

puts ""
    while n < count
        print strings[n]
        n +=1
    end
here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
puts open('file.txt').readlines.sort
```

А если хочется потренироваться в алгоритмике:

```
def bubble(list)

    sorted = list.clone

    for i in 0..(sorted.length - 1)
        for j in 0..(sorted.length - i - 2)
            if (sorted[j + 1] <=> sorted[j]) == -1
                sorted[j], sorted[j + 1] = sorted[j + 1], sorted[j]
            end
        end
    end

    return sorted
end

puts bubble(open('file.txt').readlines)
```